# boost async_read_some/async_receive behaves as if MSG_PEEK is always on

Tags: sockets, boost-asio

I have the following problem.

I start an async_receive on a tcp socket.
Callback is called with some data 
I start another async receive on the socket.
Callback is called but the buffer also contains the data from the previous call. Behaves as if i called recv with MSG_PEEK flag, although i did no such thing.

I even tried to called the version with message flags argument = 0 and same effect.

How can i disable this behaviour?. I would like the first call to eat the data from the kernel buffers after each successfull async handler call.

Mihai

Comment: Impossible to answer without your code, we need to see how you're handling the buffers you pass to `async_read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've fixed the problem. It was a send problem. I was reusing the vector of buffers passed to async_write.

Comment: this really isn't a very useful answer for other users who may experience the same problem and find your question via the search engine. As my comment to your question indicates, you should update the question with your code, then put the solution in this answer.